# How to call/return asp.net mvc view from angular or with angular defined variable/s

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    $scope.showDetails = function (dashboard_item) {
    $log.debug("clicked");
    $http({
        url: '/Details/Details',
        method: 'GET',
        data: { name: dashboard_item.FName }
    })
};
```

This will call method, but won't pass name to it and will return to angular controller. Instead of opening/staying on new page.

```
*onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Details", new {name = $scope.dashboard_item.Fname })'"
```

This will properly open/return new page/view, but it can't access angular variable in razor/server side.

There doesn't seem to be any good examples or any information how to do something as simple as this.
I know I should be probably be using angular routes, but I've got no clue how and honestly I would rather stick with asp MVC routing, but anything at this point would do..

TLDR I want to return/call/open new MVC view while passing parameters to it

Comment: I would highly prefer solution that doesn't use href as I need to make table column clickable as link,  both currently posted involve a href and doesnt work with onclick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<a ng-href="@Url.Action("Details","Details")?name={{dashboard_item.Fname}}">Link</a>
```

in your razor view where you are using this angular controller.

**UPDATE**

To use it on all the elements, not only the anchor, you can create this function in your angular controller:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
  $window.location.href = path;
};
```

and then on your view you can use something like this:

```
<tr ng-click="go('@Url.Action("CompanyProfileDetails","User")?name=' + profile.Name)">
  *another code here*
</tr>
```

Comment: Got a solution that doesnt use href, need to have an object clickable not just a link?

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius, but the anchor is also clickable :) so did you find the solution with button? or should I write the example with the button?

Comment: I need it for table row, so button wont do much good either probably

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius, please check the update of the answer.

Comment: cheers it works, I've tried similar approach where I've tried to create link in angular and use angular path for it, but that got no where

Answer (score 0):

As the razor executes in server side pass new object from client side is not possible but you can do pass as url params

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details","Details")?name={{dashboard_item.Fname}}">Your link here </a>
```

Comment: doesn't work at least with angular throws error and variable stays as variable name, not its value `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Details")?name={{dashboard_item.Fname}})'"` as I need to make object clickable I cant use href, shouldn't make much difference